# Anylogic 7: Different Random Generators for different processes

Tags: random, anylogic

I'm trying to archive the following within Anylogic: I have several processes that are all somehow distributed. These distributions involve random number generation.

As of my understanding anylogic creates one random number stream from which any process takes its random numbers. But actually I want to have another random number stream for each process. Anyone has an idea how to do this?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do and that you're able to help me.

Comment: Why would you have different random number generators in the first place? Is that because you cannot access the same generator from the different processes, or because you do not want for some reason?

Comment: It is quite common to want different generators for different processes. Actually, it is good modelling practice. The reason is that otherwise, some model design can lead to processes not being independent anymore where there should be independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own random number generators like this: `Random rng1 = new Random();` and use them in distributions like this `uniform(2,5,rng1)`. This way rng1 is used as random number stream instead of the default one.

Comment: Thank you a lot - it's much easier than i thought :D

Comment: If you want to manke sure that it is the same random numer you get in each simulation. You can use a fixed seed. `Random rnd = new Random(434)`